# How to set maximum radius of polygon

Tags: r, r-sf

I draw a map in which points are represented as polygons. The points are found close to a southern state border. The code is:

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

long   <- c( 4.676119175,  4.53172103 ,  4.939782877,  5.074127987,  5.072757119)
lat    <- c(51.477299959, 51.589766239, 51.624436295, 51.520707997, 51.631483055)
labs   <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
colors <- rainbow(length(labs))

df <- data.frame(ID = labs, X = long, Y = lat)
points  <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(df, coords = c("X", "Y")))
points0 <- st_set_crs(points, 4326)

area <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = c('netherlands'), scale = 'large', returnclass = 'sf')

polys <- points %>% st_union() %>% st_voronoi() %>% st_cast() %>% st_set_crs(., 4326)
polys <- polys[unlist(st_intersects(points0, polys))] %>% st_intersection(y = area)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%
  addPolygons     (data        = polys,
                   fillColor   = colors,
                   fillOpacity = 1,
                   weight      = 0.5, 
                   color       = "black") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng         = long,
                   lat         = lat,
                   label       = labs, 
                   color       = "black",
                   radius      = 5,
                   weight      = 1,
                   fill        = TRUE,
                   fillColor   = colors,
                   fillOpacity = 1)
```

The results looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that the polygons get stretched out to the north way to much. This may be solved by setting a bounding box, but I would prefer to solve this by setting a maximum size (or radius) for the polygons. How exactly can I set the maximum radius?

Comment: Where does `ne_countries` come from?

Comment: ne countries comes from `rnaturalearth::ne_countries()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding another call of `sf::st_intersection()` with an object of buffered points.

You have two alternatives:

- intersect with a buffer of a single lab - number C seems a good candidate, as it is placed in the middle
- intersect with pairwise buffers of each lab; `purrr:map2()` will be your friend here for pairwise intersection

I find the results of a single intersection more visually pleasing, but this may be not the most important factor so make your own choice...

As a comment: my natural earth is a bit buggy at the moment, so I am using GISCO by Eurostat as a source of map of the Netherlands instead; in a high resolution because I really dig the tiny exclaves of Belgium...

```
library(leaflet)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)

long   <- c( 4.676119175,  4.53172103 ,  4.939782877,  5.074127987,  5.072757119)
lat    <- c(51.477299959, 51.589766239, 51.624436295, 51.520707997, 51.631483055)
labs   <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
colors <- rainbow(length(labs))

points <- data.frame(ID = labs, X = long, Y = lat) %>% 
    st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326) %>% 
    mutate(ID = ordered(ID))

area <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = "NL", resolution = "01") # my Natural Earth is buggy at the momemt

# intersection with a single buffer around C
polys <- points %>% 
    st_union() %>% 
    st_voronoi() %>%
    st_cast() %>% 
    st_set_crs(., 4326) %>% 
    st_intersection(area) %>% 
    st_intersection(st_buffer(dplyr::filter(points, ID == "C"), units::as_units(30000, "m"))) %>% 
    st_as_sf() %>% 
    st_join(points) # add back labs id's

palette <- colorFactor(palette = colors,
                      domain = polys$ID)

leaflet(data = polys) %>% 
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>% 
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(ID),
                stroke = F) %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = points,
                     fillColor = ~palette(ID),
                     stroke = F,
                     fillOpacity = 1)
```

[image]

```
# intersection with pairwise buffers
polys <- points %>% 
    st_union() %>% 
    st_voronoi() %>%
    st_cast() %>% 
    st_set_crs(., 4326) %>% 
    st_intersection(area) %>% 
    purrr::map2(st_geometry(st_buffer(points, units::as_units(30000, "m"))), st_intersection) %>% 
    st_as_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
    st_as_sf() %>% 
    st_join(points) # add back labs id's

mapview::mapview(polys)
```

[image: pairwise buffers]

Comment: Wonderful! I get a warning: st_voronoi does not correctly triangulate longitude/latitude data. Can I just ignore this warning?

Comment: When using leaflet in order to show the map, the dots have other colors and the voronoi cells. How can this be solved?

Comment: Unless you are going for an engineering quality accuracy (which seems not to be the case) the warning about voronoi polygons can be ignored. If yes then consider transforming both points and country polygon to https://epsg.io/28992

Comment: as for the different colors in leaflet: this is really a separate question, but my suggestion would be to use `leaflet::colorFactor()`, perhaps with converting the labs to factors beforehand. An example in use can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533583/r-leaflet-adding-colors-for-character-variables

Comment: Thanks. I did not succeed with `colorFactor()`. Originally `polys[unlist(st_intersects(points0, polys))]` ensured that voronoi cells and dots got the same color. Is it possible to reinclude this somehow in the code?

Comment: i have amended the answer to include the leaflet call yet again; note that I have also converted the IDs to ordered factor. I am using your colors object for the palette. The second part / if required / could follow the same principle if necessary...